# iOS build and publish through AppCenter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I’m now looking into AppCenter and looks like it will both build and publish an app to both Apple App Store and Google Play.

Does this mean iOS development for Windows based developers becomes a Mac-free process? We can already test the app on an iOS device through an USB connection and HotReload so the only dependency to Xcode is build and publish. Trying to understand if I’m missing something.

Comment: [I haven't tried this myself.] [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted) mention using a Microsoft-hosted Xcode agent. So, Xcode in the cloud. If you have problems getting the result to successfully upload to Apple, get hold of a Mac the ***first*** time you publish the app to app store. Googling `can appcenter build and publish to ios without a mac` I saw one article suggesting that.

Comment: I see there are also other commercial services that rent time on mac via internet. (ex: macincloud). Including ability to run Xcode. So whatever licensing Apple requires, these vendors must have resolved. I assume that means Microsoft has done the same.

Comment: IME: I would highly recommend testing the actual app on local devices (hotreload is a nice to have for XAML changes but it does not provide a full picture of the complete compiled app). And since new MacMinis are cheaper than iOS devices the ROI of the Mini is really fast.

Comment: I think it's technically feasible to do this, but I would not want to deploy and support an iOS app if I did not have a local Mac for testing and troubleshooting

Comment: Why not use AppCenter to build and upload and then test on a real device through Test Flight? I currently rent a Mac through MacInCloud and all I use it for is build and upload. I still do my testing on real devices. So if I can take the Mac out of the equation, I’d be very happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically YES, however there are some limitations that you need know.

1.Luckily, we have free hosted Mac machines on CI/CD platforms like App Center or Azure DevOps. Or a service like MacInCloud. However, if you do the last compilation that you are going to send to the App Store, then you have to compile the app on a physical Mac machine.

2.You have the Hot Restart that allows you to deploy with the iTunes to your local iPhone/iPad without Mac machines, however, there are some limitations for it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#limitations